# How do I prove that the set of zero-order differential operators on $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is $\mathbb{C}[x]$ itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, operator-algebras

> **Definition.** Let $R$ be a commutative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. A linear operator $D\colon R\to R$ is an operator
> of order zero if, for every $r\in R$, the operator $$[D,r]=Dr-rD\colon
>  R\to R$$ is equal to the zero operator.

> **Definition.** A linear operator $D\colon R\to R$ is an operator of order $k$ or less, where $k\ge 1$ is an integer, if for every $r\in R$
> the operator $[D,r]$ is an operator of order $k-1$ or less. The set of
> all operators on $R$ of order $k$ or less is denoted by
> $\mathcal{D}_{k}(R)$.

The alebra of differential operators on $R$ is defined as $$\mathcal{D}(R):=\bigcup_{k\ge 0} \mathcal{D}_k(R).$$

> **Theorem.** Prove that $\mathcal{D}_0(\mathbb{C}[x])=\mathbb{C}[x].$

What I have done so far:

Let $f\in R=\mathbb{C}[x]$. We can think of $f$ as an operator on $R$ as follows: for any $g\in R$, we set $$f(g):=fg.$$ Then $f$ is an operator of order zero because $[f, g]=fg-gf=0$ for all $g\in R$. This means that $f\in \mathcal{D}_0(R)$, so that $R\subseteq \mathcal{D}_0(R)$.

I am having trouble proving the other inclusion and don't have an idea for how to go about doing so.

Comment: Let $D\in\mathcal{D}_0(R)$ and take $r\in R=\mathbb{C}[x]$. Since $1\in R$, then $Dr = D(r1) = [D,r]1+rD1 = f(r)$, where $f=D1\in R$.

Comment: @user90189: Thank you so much!